# Case error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, case

I am trying an merge operation and insert in specific column the following strings based on case conditions in SQL Server. However, I am getting:

> an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
> condition is expected

I am getting error on the third WHEN CASE.

```
CASE 
WHEN SOURCE.oID NOT NULL THEN 'Type A'
WHEN SOURCE.bID IS NULL THEN 'Type B' 
WHEN SOURCE.oID AND SOURCE.bID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Type C'
ELSE 'null'
END
```

Comment: . . What is `<<` ?

Comment: Looks like an expression is needed before `AND`.

Comment: Can you try : WHEN SOURCE.oID IS NOT NULL AND SOURCE.bID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Type C'

Comment: Vote to leave open, this is a common error when starting out in `SQL` that you learn to look out for, `AND` must be used to combine two boolean expressions, it can't be used to combine two fields so they are evaluated together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

third line is missing the first condition criteria should be something like this:

```
WHEN SOURCE.oID IS NULL AND SOURCE.bID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Type C'
```